# app upload application loader

Tags: iphone, upload, app-store

how long does it take usually to submit an app within the application loader from apple? now it's testing connectivity for 18 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should (force) quit the app loader and try again.

In my experience one out of ten uploads to itunes connect needs a force quit at some point.
But I have a poor internet connection with lots of packet loss.

Comment: i got it uploaded.. takes around 30 minutes

Comment: That seems a long time! How big is your app?